# External FLASH slow verification with STM32cubeProgrammer

Tags: external, loader, stm32cubeide

I'm working with an STM32F469 chip with a Micron MT25Q Quad_SPI Flash. To program the Flash, there needs to be an external loader program developed. That's all working, but the problem is that verification of the QSPI Flash is extremely slow.

Looking in the log file, it shows that the Flash is being programmed in 150K byte blocks. However, the verification is being done in 1K byte blocks. In addition, the chip is re-initialized before each block check. I've tried this with both through STM32cubeIDE and in STM32cubeProgrammer directly.

The external programmer program include the correct chip configuration information and specifies a 64K page size. I don't see how to get the programmer to use a larger block size. It looks like it understands what part of the SRAM is used and is using the balance of the 256K in the on-board SRAM for programming the QSPI Flash. It could use the same size for reading the data back or use the Verify() function in the external loader. It's calling Read() and then checking the data itself.

Any thought or hints?

Let me add some observations on creating a new external loader. The first observation is "Don't." If you can pick a supported external chip and pin it out to use an existing loader, then do that. STM provides just 4 example programs but they must have 50 external loaders. If the hardware design copies the schematic for a demo board that has an external loader, you should be fine and avoid doing the development work.

The external loader is not a complete executable. It provides a set of functions to do basic operations like Init(), Erase(), Read() and Write(). The trick is that there is no main() and no start-up code is run when the program starts.

The external loader is an ELF file, renamed to "*.stldr". The programming tool looks into the debug information to find the location of the functions. It then sets the registers to provide the parameters, the PC to run the function, and then let's it run. There's some super-clever work going on to make this work. The programmer looks at the returned value (R0) to see if things pass or not. It can also figure out if the function has crashed the core or otherwise timed-out.

What makes writing the external super fun is that the debugger is running the program so there's no debugger available to see what the code is doing. I settled on outputting errors, and encoded information, on the return() from the called functions to give hints as to what was happening.

The external loader isn't a "full" program. Without the startup code, lots of on-chip stuff isn't set up and some just isn't going to work. At least I couldn't figure it out. I'm not sure if it wasn't configured right or the debugger was blocking its use. Looking at the example external loaders, they are written in a very simple way and do not call the HAL or use interrupts. You'll need to provide  core set-up functions to configure the clock chains. That Hal_Delay() method will never return as the timers and/or interrupts aren't working. I could never make them work and suspect the NVIC was somehow being disabled. I ended up replacing the HAL_delay() function with a for loop that spun based on core clock rate and a the instruction cycles per loop.

The app note suggests developing a stand-alone program to debug the basic capabilities. That's a good idea but a challenge. Prior to starting the external loader, I had the QSPI doing the needed operations but from a C++ application calling the HAL. Creating an external loader from that was a long exercise in stripping out and replacing functionality. A hint is that the examples are written at a register level. I'm not that good to deal directly with the QuadSPI peripheral and the chip's instruction set at the same time.

The normal start-up of a program is eliminated. Everything that's done before the main() is called (E.g., in startup_stm32f469nihx.s) is up to you. This includes setting the clock chains to boost the core clock and get the peripheral buses working. The program runs in the on-chip SRAM so any initialized variables are loaded correctly. There's no moving data needed but the stack and uninitialized data areas could/should still be zeroed.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Today I've faced the same issue.

I was able to improve the Verify speed with two simple steps, but Verify still much slower than programming and this is strange...
If anyone find a way to change the 1KB block read of STM32CubeProgrammer I would like to know =).
Follow the changes I made to improve a bit the performance.

1. Add a kind of lock in the Init Function to avoid multiple initializations. This was the most significant change because I'am checking the Flash ID in my initialization proccess. Other aproachs could be safer but this simple code snippet worked to me.

   ```
   int Init(void)
   {
       static uint32_t lock;

       if(lock != 0x43213CA5)
       {
           lock = 0x43213CA5;

           /* Init procedure goes here */

       }    
       return(1);
   }
   ```
2. Cache a page instead of reading the external memory for each call. This will help more if your external memory page read has too much overhead, otherwise this idea won't give relevant results.

---

Comment: Good tip to speed up the initialization.